# how to add a ID_ follow by number in a fasta file using bash

Tags: bash, awk, fasta

I have a fasta file

my_file.fasta

```
>NODE_1_length_531158 [gcode=11] [organism=Genus species] [strain=strain]
GACCATGACACGGTTGAACCAGATCAGAGAGCAGTTACAAGCCTTCCCAGAACTGAAACA
>NODE_2_length_200_ [gcode=11] [organism=Genus species] [strain=strain]
GGTGCCGACTACCGGAATCGAACTGGTGACCTACTGATTACAAGTCAGTTGCTCTACCTA
>NODE_3_length_200_ [gcode=11] [organism=Genus species] [strain=strain]
GTTGCGGGGGCCGGATTTGAACCGACGACCTTCGGGTTATGAGCCCGACGAGCTACCAAG
```

I just want to add a ID_number at begins of each sequence name (line that start with >), so I tried:

```
awk '/^>/ {$1= ">ID_" ++i $1}1' my_file.fasta > Outfile.fasta
```

but I get

```
>ID_1>NODE_1_length_531158 [gcode=11] [organism=Genus species] [strain=strain]
GACCATGACACGGTTGAACCAGATCAGAGAGCAGTTACAAGCCTTCCCAGAACTGAAACA
>ID_2>NODE_2_length_200_ [gcode=11] [organism=Genus species] [strain=strain]
GGTGCCGACTACCGGAATCGAACTGGTGACCTACTGATTACAAGTCAGTTGCTCTACCTA
>ID_3>NODE_3_length_200_ [gcode=11] [organism=Genus species] [strain=strain]
GTTGCGGGGGCCGGATTTGAACCGACGACCTTCGGGTTATGAGCCCGACGAGCTACCAAG
```

and I want to get something similar, but without the second >, I mean something similar to (>ID_Number space old_name):

```
>ID_1 NODE_1_length_531158 [gcode=11] [organism=Genus species] [strain=strain]
GACCATGACACGGTTGAACCAGATCAGAGAGCAGTTACAAGCCTTCCCAGAACTGAAACA
>ID_2 NODE_2_length_200_ [gcode=11] [organism=Genus species] [strain=strain]
GGTGCCGACTACCGGAATCGAACTGGTGACCTACTGATTACAAGTCAGTTGCTCTACCTA
>ID_3 NODE_3_length_200_ [gcode=11] [organism=Genus species] [strain=strain]
GTTGCGGGGGCCGGATTTGAACCGACGACCTTCGGGTTATGAGCCCGACGAGCTACCAAG
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple small changes to OP's current `awk` code:

```
$ awk '/^>/{$1= ">ID_" ++i " " substr($1,2)}1' my_file.fasta
>ID_1 NODE_1_length_531158 [gcode=11] [organism=Genus species] [strain=strain]
GACCATGACACGGTTGAACCAGATCAGAGAGCAGTTACAAGCCTTCCCAGAACTGAAACA
>ID_2 NODE_2_length_200_ [gcode=11] [organism=Genus species] [strain=strain]
GGTGCCGACTACCGGAATCGAACTGGTGACCTACTGATTACAAGTCAGTTGCTCTACCTA
>ID_3 NODE_3_length_200_ [gcode=11] [organism=Genus species] [strain=strain]
GTTGCGGGGGCCGGATTTGAACCGACGACCTTCGGGTTATGAGCCCGACGAGCTACCAAG
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it works well !!!!! .... Thanks  all of you !!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
>NODE_1_length_531158 [gcode=11] [organism=Genus species] [strain=strain]
GACCATGACACGGTTGAACCAGATCAGAGAGCAGTTACAAGCCTTCCCAGAACTGAAACA
>NODE_2_length_200_ [gcode=11] [organism=Genus species] [strain=strain]
GGTGCCGACTACCGGAATCGAACTGGTGACCTACTGATTACAAGTCAGTTGCTCTACCTA
>NODE_3_length_200_ [gcode=11] [organism=Genus species] [strain=strain]
GTTGCGGGGGCCGGATTTGAACCGACGACCTTCGGGTTATGAGCCCGACGAGCTACCAAG
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="^>";OFS=" "}NF==2{$1=">ID_" ++i}{print}' file.txt
```

output

```
>ID_1 NODE_1_length_531158 [gcode=11] [organism=Genus species] [strain=strain]
GACCATGACACGGTTGAACCAGATCAGAGAGCAGTTACAAGCCTTCCCAGAACTGAAACA
>ID_2 NODE_2_length_200_ [gcode=11] [organism=Genus species] [strain=strain]
GGTGCCGACTACCGGAATCGAACTGGTGACCTACTGATTACAAGTCAGTTGCTCTACCTA
>ID_3 NODE_3_length_200_ [gcode=11] [organism=Genus species] [strain=strain]
GTTGCGGGGGCCGGATTTGAACCGACGACCTTCGGGTTATGAGCCCGACGAGCTACCAAG
```

Explanation: I inform GUN `AWK` to treat `>` at beginning (`^`) as field separator (`FS`) and space as output field separator (`OFS`), then for each line if number of field is equal 2 (that is it does starts with `>`) I set first field (which is empty string before `>`) to `>ID_` concated with subsequent number. Each line is `print`ed.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: Nice use of `^` to anchor `>` so you won't corrupt input with multiple `>`s on a line. You don't need to set `OFS=" "` as that's already the default - the script could be written more concisely as just `awk -v FS='^>' 'NF==2{$1=">ID_" ++i} 1' file.txt`. It'll work in any awk, btw, not just GNU awk.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'sub(/^>/,"&ID_"(cnt+1)" "){cnt++} 1' my_file.fasta
>ID_1 NODE_1_length_531158 [gcode=11] [organism=Genus species] [strain=strain]
GACCATGACACGGTTGAACCAGATCAGAGAGCAGTTACAAGCCTTCCCAGAACTGAAACA
>ID_2 NODE_2_length_200_ [gcode=11] [organism=Genus species] [strain=strain]
GGTGCCGACTACCGGAATCGAACTGGTGACCTACTGATTACAAGTCAGTTGCTCTACCTA
>ID_3 NODE_3_length_200_ [gcode=11] [organism=Genus species] [strain=strain]
GTTGCGGGGGCCGGATTTGAACCGACGACCTTCGGGTTATGAGCCCGACGAGCTACCAAG
```